# TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, nlb

Recently we face the above issue from on of our web service log. This happens only on and off but we puzzled what may cause this error to happen. The sql is just a normal sql. First we thought this may because the long running queries but as per goggling found out that .Net 2008 will have timeout expired exception if exceed defaults 30 seconds timeout.So suspect not because the sql itself. Form the event viewer we can find NLB convergence event happen during the time. Is that NLB convergence will cause network glitch and thus cause the error triggered?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at http://serverfault.com

Comment: Hi Joshua,I have ask the question serverfault.com also.